# Support with hosting an ASP.NET application from my PC at work using IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis-express

I'm fairly new to developing with ASP.NET and in general. I have created a simple data-driven web application that will be used to display images the colors of which will be changed depending on certain criteria. I used Visual Studio 2019 to create it. When I test/run it from within VS 2019 using the "play" button, it runs perfectly and the page opens in my browser just as you would expect.

My issue is that I'm trying to deploy it to the IIS and host it from my machine here at work, so others can access the pages. I have published the application to a local file on my C:\ drive. I then open up IIS Manager and create the website by pointing to that local file. Now, when I choose to browse that site from the IIS manager, at first I was getting an error saying that access is denied.

Then I followed the instructions to configure the security on that local file folder to allow IIS_USRS to access the file, but when I run it, I just get a page that tries to load indefinitely.

What am I doing wrong? If I point the IIS Manager to the files after saving them to a location on my company's network, I again get the access is denied error.

Do I understand it correctly that IIS needs permission to access the files? If so, how do I configure it that way other than what I already tried? If I need to provide further information, please let me know. Thanks so much for your support.

Comment: You know you can create a local account on your machine (or an AD account) and run the IIS app pool as that account, and then give that account permissions to whatever it needs.

Comment: You raised a bunch of questions, and each of them have been widely discussed for decades. "I just get a page that tries to load indefinitely" can be a true question, but without troubleshooting with your browser's developer tools, and failed request tracing on IIS side, no conclusion. "saving them to a location on my company's network" is almost always a bad idea and without network administrators of your company's help I don't think you can find the right permissions to set. Please escalate to a more senior guy in your company to help, as over the internet no much help can be given.

Comment: @mason that might work in most cases, but "a location on my company's network" can be non-Windows in a company.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks for the comment. I in fact did bring this up to my company's help desk and waited a full month before they responded. They ended up connecting me with people who could not help me in the end. That's why I turned to the internet. Buuut I did reach out again to someone I know in the company who has knowledge with ASP.NET, so I'm hoping he an point me in the right direction.